# Running Selenium on EC2 works on server, but not from the browser

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, selenium, amazon-ec2, selenium-chromedriver

### TLDR;

**Python Selenium using ChromeDriver installed on EC2 instance not working when the script is called from the browser but working when same script called from the server. How to fix?**

---

Hey guys,

I have installed Python 3.6, Selenium, ChromeDriver, and Google Chrome on my AWS EC2 instance. I have also enabled HTTP/2 and given ChromeDriver permissions.

I have a test Python script, let's call it test.py.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
options = Options()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/bin/chromedriver', options=options)
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/")
element_text = driver.find_element_by_id("title").text
print(element_text)
```

In the terminal, I can simply run this script with:

```
python3 /var/app/current/scripts/test.py
```

and it works with no problem.

However, if I try to run this same script from the browser, (note that the URL is HTTPS), I get the following error:

```
[mpm_event:notice] AH00493: SIGUSR1 received.  Doing graceful restart
[http2:warn] AH02951: mod_ssl does not seem to be enabled
[lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[mpm_event:notice] AH00489: Apache/2.4.41 (Amazon) configured -- resuming normal operations
[core:notice] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[mpm_event:warn] AH00488: long lost child came home!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/app/current/scripts/test.py", line 3, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'
```

stating that there is no module named 'selenium'.

Note that I am calling it from the browser using PHP:

```
$output=shell_exec('python3 /var/app/current/scripts/test.py');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
```

I also know that the PHP is working because if I change test.py to simply:

```
import datetime from datetime
print(datetime.now())
```

It will print the date and time.

So, there seems to be a problem with Selenium in particular, but only from the browser.

Does anyone have any idea what this could be?

I appreciate all of your help / comments!

Thanks a lot :)

Brad

---

### EDIT

I have since changed the script to:

```
sudo PYTHONUSERBASE=/home/ec2-user/.local python3 /var/app/current/scripts/test.py
```

and am now getting a slightly different error:

```
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

I think I'll have to create a virtualenvironment and then use that when I call the script again.

Comment: Selenium framework is installed properly into the server?

Comment: yep, I can run python3 /var/app/current/scripts/test.py from the server, which imports webdriver from selenium, just fine.

Comment: Another question is, do you have the correct permissions for your folders in the server? I mean when the script is going to retrieve selenium or other packages will need permissions to do that. Can you check that too?

Comment: I am thinking that may be the problem. I tried to give the folder the ability to be executed by others: sudo chmod 711 /home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver, but that didn't seem to help. Actually, now I can't even run test.py in the terminal. I then tried sudo chmod 777 /home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver (I realize 777 is dangerous... I just wanted to test it and quickly remove it), but this also didn't help.